# Does the molecular composition of human body change after a period of time?

Tags: human-biology, molecular-biology, cell-biology

I was discussing change in human biology over time and my two in-laws charged in saying, "we're molecularly different after *x*". I didn't pay attention to what time period they exactly mentioned (hence *x*).

I am familiar with how mainstream media warps research data to be entertaining. So would serious researchers and scientists consider bold statements such as "we (humans) are completely different after 6 years!" as nothing more than anecdotal?

I'm not talking about decomposition after death but rather about processes in the live body.